# PSWindowsUpdate blank output when running Get-WUList from Powershell script

Tags: powershell, script

I use the PSWindowsUpdate Module to update most of the machines at my workplace. However, when running the Get-WUList (or Get-WUInstall) command via a Powershell script, I get blank out put as seen in the attached picture. I'd really like to be able to see what updates are going to install/are installing. [image: PSWindowsUpdate Blank Output]

Whenever I run the commands manually, everything shows up as it should. I've tried messing around with write-host command, but end up with a mess of text that's not really decipherable. Anyone have any ideas on how I might get the output of Get-WUList/Get-WUInstall when executed via a script and not manually?

*I should note that I use Remote Desktop Manager (RDM) to remote into my systems. They have a feature called the Remote Desktop Agent that allows for executing scripts on multiple machines at the same time via the RDM interface.

#### EDITED TO INCLUDE SCRIPT

```
Echo "Enabling Windows Update Services"
Get-Service wuauserv | Set-Service -StartupType Manual
Get-Service bits | Set-Service -StartupType Manual

Echo "Enabling updates for additional Microsoft components and software"
Add-WUServiceManager -ServiceID 7971f918-a847-4430-9279-4a52d1efe18d -Confirm:$false

Echo "Querying Microsoft Update Server for Windows Updates"
Get-WUList -MicrosoftUpdate | Select Title, KB, Status

Echo "Hiding Unnecessary Updates"
Hide-WUUpdate -Title "*Visio*"    -Confirm:$false
Hide-WUUpdate -Title "*OneDrive*" -Confirm:$false
Hide-WUUpdate -Title "*OneNote*"  -Confirm:$false
Hide-WUUpdate -Title "*Outlook*"  -Confirm:$false
Hide-WUUpdate -Title "*Skype*"    -Confirm:$false

Echo "Downloading and Installing Windows Updates"
Get-WUInstall -MicrosoftUpdate -AcceptAll -IgnoreReboot | Select Title, KB

Echo "Stopping Windows Update Services"
Get-Service wuauserv | Stop-Service -PassThru | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
Get-Service bits | Stop-Service -PassThru | Set-Service -StartupType Disabled
```

Comment: You are asking how to make get-wulist and get-wuinstall to work but you just said they are working. Your issue is your script, so why not post the script? Obviously that is where the problem is and we are just guessing otherwise.

Comment: The script just uses the same exact commands that I manually type. There's nothing different. The script works, it simply doesn't display the results in the console like when I manually type the same commands. I will gladly post the script, but I doubt it will be much help as they are just the standard PSWindowsUpdate commands.

Comment: @Appleoddity I've included my script. I've also noticed that the Hide-WUUpdate commands doesn't work in the script, but does if I manually type the commands. Just to clarify again, the script does in fact update the computer, it just doesn't output any visible information detailing what updates are available/are installing. From the picture I included, you can see that the output between the "Querying Microsoft..." and "Hiding Windows Updates..." (bottom of pic, cut off) is blank.